# Is it possible to reuse a datalist on multiple elements?

Tags: html, css, datalist

I have defined it and placed in the `<head>` tag:

```
<datalist id="colors">

  <option>#ff0000</option>    <!-- red            -->
  <option>#FF5100</option>    <!-- red orange     -->
  <option>#FF7F00</option>    <!-- orange         -->
  <option>#FFBE00</option>    <!-- yellow orange  -->
  <option>#FFFF00</option>    <!-- yellow         -->

  <option>#C0FF00</option>    <!-- yellow green   -->
  <option>#00FF00</option>    <!-- green -->
  <option>#007F7F</option>    <!-- Blue Green     -->
  <option>#0000FF</option>    <!-- Blue -->
  <option>#5C00FF</option>    <!-- Blue Violet    -->

  <option>#7F00FF</option>    <!-- Violet         -->
  <option>#BF007F</option>    <!-- Red Violet     -->
  <option>#FFFFFF</option>    <!-- White          -->
  <option>#DADADA</option>    <!-- Gray1          -->
  <option>#B6B6B6</option>    <!-- Gray2          -->

  <option>#929292</option>    <!-- Gray3          -->
  <option>#6D6D6D</option>    <!-- Gray4          -->
  <option>#494949</option>    <!-- Gray5          -->
  <option>#242424</option>    <!-- Gray6          -->
  <option>#000000</option>    <!-- Black          -->

</datalist>
```

and it seems to work but I am getting errors:

```
Unexpected end tag (head) - ignored.
```

Where should I put it?

Comment: Why would you place it in `<head>` tag? Add it to the `<body>`

Comment: For no other reason than I don't know where to put it.

Comment: You should place it exactly in the place you want it to appear in your document.. between <body></body>, and should probably add values to those options.

Comment: Thanks.  I thought, for some reason, that it had to be outside the body to be reused.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: what component is returning this error? I know browsers to report Javascript errors in the debugging environments, but HTML?

Comment: I should have indicated it's a formatting/parsing error.  I'm using Caret in Chrome.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To answer first the question in the title: yes, you can use the same `datalist` element in multiple controls, by using its `id` attribute value in different `input` elements, e.g.

```
<datalist id="colors">...</datalist>
<label for="car">Color of your car:</label> <input type="color" id="car" list="colors">
<label for="tie">Color of your tie:</label> <input type="color" id="tie" list="colors">
```

Regarding the question “Where should I put it?”, the HTML5 LC says about [`datalist`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-datalist-element):

> Contexts in which this element can be used:
>       Where phrasing content is expected.

This means pretty much any place inside the document `body`, but not in `head`. When used properly, its placement does not matter, since it generates no visible content as such. You can put it e.g. right before (or after) the first `input` element that refers to it or, if you prefer, at the start or end of `body`.

However, *if* use markup like `<option>#ff0000</option>`, as opposite to `<option value="#ffff00">`, in this context, then the placement matters, since now there is visible content (the string #ff0000). On old browsers that do not support the `datalist` element, such content will be shown where you place the element.

If you are using `<input type="color">`, which seems probable, then you should consider what happens on IE that does not support that element type. The problem is that sufficiently new versions of IE support `datalist` but even IE 11 still implements `<input type="color"> as a simple text box,``. This means that the user, on clicking element, would see a dropdown list of color codes like #FF0000. For this reason, unless IE is irrelevant, you should specify a visible name for the color in a`label` attribute, e.g.

```
  <option value="#ff0000" label="red">
  <option value="#FF5100" label="red orange">
```

In this approach, the `datalist` element could still be placed almost anywhere inside `body` and could be referenced by more than one `input` element.

Comment: Outstanding answer!  Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Use by every option not

`<option>...</option>` but `<option value="...">`

Comment: This might be useful information, but it does not address the question asked.

Answer (score 1):

I've run the skeleton snippet below in these browsers:

- Chrome 35 Mac -> Works fine
- Mozilla 30 Mac -> Works fine, though no list control, only bare input field
- IE 11 -> works fine, no list control.
- From IE 9 downwards the page get scrambled.
- Safari 7.0.4 can't handle it, it shows no list. Needs probably some other details.

So your error comes probably from another aspect.

According to HTML5 specs, the element should be used where "Phrasing content" is placed. http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-datalist-element. This is the text of the document, as I see, the `<body>`: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#phrasing-content-1

**EDIT:**
Sometimes it's useful to go to the good ol' W3 validator: http://validator.w3.org/check

If I put the `datalist` in the head, the validator reports something about "straying head end tag". So This should be one source of the problem.

---

Snippet:

```
    <html>
      <head>
        <datalist id="colors">
          <option>#ff0000</option>    <!-- red            -->
          <option>#FF5100</option>    <!-- red orange     -->
          <option>#FF7F00</option>    <!-- orange         -->
          <option>#FFBE00</option>    <!-- yellow orange  -->
          <option>#FFFF00</option>    <!-- yellow         -->
          <option>#C0FF00</option>    <!-- yellow green   -->

          <option>#00FF00</option>    <!-- green -->
          <option>#007F7F</option>    <!-- Blue Green     -->
          <option>#0000FF</option>    <!-- Blue -->
          <option>#5C00FF</option>    <!-- Blue Violet    -->

          <option>#7F00FF</option>    <!-- Violet         -->
          <option>#BF007F</option>    <!-- Red Violet     -->
          <option>#FFFFFF</option>    <!-- White          -->
          <option>#DADADA</option>    <!-- Gray1          -->
          <option>#B6B6B6</option>    <!-- Gray2          -->

          <option>#929292</option>    <!-- Gray3          -->
          <option>#6D6D6D</option>    <!-- Gray4          -->
          <option>#494949</option>    <!-- Gray5          -->
          <option>#242424</option>    <!-- Gray6          -->
          <option>#000000</option>    <!-- Black          -->
    </datalist>
  </head>
<body>

  <input list="colors" />

</body>
</html>
```